# PhpStorm excluding folders from test source

Tags: testing, phpunit, phpstorm

I'm using PHPUnit to run tests in PhpStorm. The tests source folder has been set that when right clicking the folder, PhpStorm runs all the tests in that folder. However there is one folder of tests that I don't want to run when right clicking "run tests".

I've removed that folder from the testsuite in the `phpunit.xml` so that it doesn't run specific tests from the terminal, however they still run when right clicking on the folder.

Is there any way to exclude a folder from the test sources in PhpStorm or is it simply not possible?

Comment: Create Run/Debug Configuration for PHPUnit testing, configure it and use it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need specific files, but you don't want to completely remove them, you can temporarily exclude these files from the project. Excluded files are ignored by code completion, navigation and inspections.

To exclude a file, you need to mark it as a plain text file. You can always return excluded files to their original state.

1. Right-click the necessary file in the directory tree of the
   Project tool window.
2. Select Mark as Plain Text from the menu. Plain text files are
   marked with the plain text icon icon in the directory tree.

To revert the changes, right-click the file and select Mark as  from the menu.

Here is the source : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html

Peace !

Comment: Tried the above advice to change a test to plain text, but it still runs that test when clicking run tests.